# When voting to close/flag as a duplicate, the Vote to Close/Flag Question button is disabled when the "back" button is pressed

Tags: bug, close-dialog, flag-dialog

When voting to close or flag a question as a duplicate, if you choose a duplicate target, then press the "Back" button *(not the "back to questions" button)*, then press the "Duplicate" close reason again, your previously chosen duplicate is still selected, but the Vote to Close button is disabled.

I initially ran across this while performing [this review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/76743), but I was able to achieve the same results from attempting to vote to close any question (that is to say, being in the review queue is not required to perform this).

Here's a .gif demonstration of me performing this:

[image: Gif of clicking dupe target, pressing back, then pressing Duplicate close reason, and not being able to vote to close]

This appears to be unintentional behavior given that I would now have to manually clear out the URL from the dupe target text box (or press the "back to questions" button) and select the duplicate target I wanted again in order to vote to close. I imagine that the correct behavior would be to retain the ability to vote to close in this scenario. Alternatively, this could reset this panel as though the user had pressed the "back to questions" button.

This affects both the flag dialog and the close vote dialog. Here's a [gif demonstration of this affecting the flag dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bakC3.gif).

Could this be fixed?