# URL text box is no longer autofocused in duplicate flag dialog

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions, keyboard-shortcuts

Reproduce:

- Goto any question
- Enable keyboard shortcuts, and press <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>
  (or alternatively just click Flag->a duplicate)
- Observe that the text box is not autofocused. (so you have to click on it or press <kbd>Tab</kbd> three times to focus it)

I remember that it worked before, and I checked the code and [the code used to focus the text box is still there](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=51356414#51356414).

Confirmed on a QtWebEngine-based browser and [Firefox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=51356418#51356418).

*Probably related: [When voting to close/flag as a duplicate, the Vote to Close/Flag Question button is disabled when the "back" button is pressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359672/when-voting-to-close-flag-as-a-duplicate-the-vote-to-close-flag-question-button) (because both are caused by the recent UI change?)*

Comment: Just to make it more explicit, auto-focus *works* if you go to **needs improvement** -> **Duplicate**. That's for both keyboard navigation (**m** -> **f** -> **3** -> **1**) and non-shortcut navigation. Identical for **Close** -> **Duplicate** (**m** -> **c** -> **1** using keyboard shortcuts) So, only the direct flag route doesn't work.